# Why sublist is not working on List<Object>?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to get subList from `List<Object>` this way,

My actual map data before doing sublist is this way,

```
Converted Map{Demography=[[D11,D22,D99]], Paper=[[[EEE,RRR,TTT],[QQQ,WWW,EEE],[UUU,III,OOO]]], Hunt=[[HUT,HUG,HUE]], Camp=[[COL,CIL,CPL]]
```

and my code is this,

```
public class PosTest {
    HashMap<String, Object> uiMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PosTest mm = new PosTest();
        mm.getSupplierInfo();
    }
    public void getSupplierInfo()
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        jsonMap.put("Camp","[COL,CIL,CPL]");
        jsonMap.put("Demography","[D11,D22,D99]");
        jsonMap.put("Hunt","[HUT,HUG,HUE]");
        jsonMap.put("Paper","[[EEE,RRR,TTT],[QQQ,WWW,EEE],[UUU,III,OOO]]");

        Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> i = jsonMap.entrySet().iterator();
        Entry<String, Object> e = null;
        List<Object> eValue = null;
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            e = i.next();
            eValue = Arrays.asList(e.getValue());
            uiMap.put(e.getKey(), eValue.subList(0, 1));
        }  
        System.out.println("Converted Map" + uiMap);        

    } 
}
```

Then when i call `uiMap.put(e.getKey(), eValue.subList(0, 1));` i should get only 0,1 of values from list, i.e,

```
Converted Map{Demography=[D11,D22], Paper=[[EEE,RRR,TTT],[QQQ,WWW,EEE]], Hunt=[HUT,HUG]], Camp=[COL,CIL]}
```

But My output from that code is `Converted Map{Demography=[[D11,D22,D99]], Paper=[[[EEE,RRR,TTT],[QQQ,WWW,EEE],[UUU,III,OOO]]], Hunt=[[HUT,HUG,HUE]], Camp=[[COL,CIL,CPL]]}`

Why all the list values are returned without sublist (0,1) and also one extra brace is added?

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: because `Arrays.asList()` doesn't parse the string to a list, it just creates a one-item list containing this string.

Comment: how can we achieve this?

Comment: You should really use an actual type parameter for List and Map.  `<Object>` effectively turns off all type checking.  I suspect that is related to why you are seeing unexpected results.

Comment: @Sasha Salauyou is there any other way to acheive this?

Comment: @user1660325 the only way is to write a code that parses the string into a list.

Comment: @markspace i tried casting map<string,object> to map<list> but it did not happend..can you suggest me something else?

Comment: even i tried eValue = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(e.getValue())); this but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

By this:

```
jsonMap.put("Hunt","[HUT,HUG,HUE]");
```

you don't put a list as a value, you put **the only string**. And this:

```
eValue = Arrays.asList(e.getValue());
```

doesn't magically parse `"[COL,CIL,CPL]"` to a list, it just creates one-item list containing that single string, which `subList(0, 1)` returns itself (as it has only one item).

So, first change the type of `jsonMap` to `Map<String, List<String>>`, and put items by:

```
jsonMap.put("Hunt", Arrays.asList("HUT", "HUG", "HUE"));
jsonMap.put("Hunt", Arrays.asList("D11", "D22", "D99"));
//...
```

then, to get a sublist, call:

```
uiMap.put(key, jsonMap.get(key).subList(0, 1));
```

Comment: I worked with List<String> and it worked... i want for List<Object>  only

Comment: @user1660325 you may leave it `List<Object>`, but you will need to cast after getting a value from the map. Inconvinient and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you assuming that Java can interpret `"[COL,CIL,CPL]"` as a list? It cannot. It’s one object of type `String`.

When you call `Arrays.asList()`, because of varargs, Java produces first an array of one String element, then `asList()` converts that into a list of one element. The `subList(0, 1)` of this list is the same list. This is why you get the same thing out as you put in.